AVRoutePickerView() Bug
On my end showing same option "iPhone" and "iPhone". While this should be "iPhone" and "Speaker". Reply please, if found solution for this. This comes only when once I did select speaker and going back again to iPhone.
I am exacting behaviour of AVRoutePickerView expected?
